# How do I compile my pyglet app and all the resources into one exe file?

Tags: python, compilation, exe, pyinstaller, pyglet

I'm working on a school project where we needs to create an app. I used a lot of wav files and also some png and gif files. I used pyinstaller to compile everything into one exe file and it gets the job done. However, it seems like the resources mentioned aren't coming with it. So I did some research and I messed around with the spec file and in the datas field, I added:

```
datas=[('*.wav','.'),('*.png','.'),('*.gif','.')],
```

Then I compile it again. I wrote

```
py -m PyInstaller py -m PyInstaller Main.py --icon=icon.ico --name "Main" --distpath "Final Program"  --noconsole
```

and when I open the file, it freezes. How do I fix this? If I don't do --onefile, it works fine. If I do

```
py -m PyInstaller Main.py --icon=icon.ico --name "Main" --distpath "Final Program" --add-data "*.wav;." --add-data "*.png;." --add-data "*.gif;." --noconsole
```

It also works fine but it creates a folder. Are there any ways to make it all into one executable file?
I'm really new to pyinstaller as well as pyglet.

Thanks.

Comment: Generally, even with compiled languages such as C++, the images and other resource files are not compiled into the EXE. Just look at the folder where you install Microsoft Office or any game and you will see many folders of resource files.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Code-Apprentice's comment. However, maybe you want to look into the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module. You would have only one resource file, save space and add a little layer of obscurity until someone uses a zip program. You even don't need to unpack your resources on disc but rather use [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.StringIO) or [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=bytesio#io.BytesIO) to store them in memory.

Loading times, at least for starting, would obviously increase.